# I just downloaded After Effects for windows 10. And whenever I try to open it, I get the following error:

Tags: opencv, adobe, after-effects

I have a new computer for making videos so I decided to buy Adobe After Effects. It finally downloaded, but I kept getting an error every time I tried to launch it (as seen in the title). Do any of you geniuses know a fix to this? "The code execution cannot proceed because opencv_world341.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." How do I fix this?
I have already tried reinstalling after effects. (I don't know much what else to do).

I don't have any code. (it's after effects)

I expect it would launch like it did on my other computer, but it popped up with an error on this computer instead.

Comment: did you try contacting Adobe? Maybe that version is broken/incomplete?!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases/)?
If that doesn't do the trick, un-install using [Revo](https://www.revouninstaller.com/), then try re-installing after a reboot.